# About WebGet(UriTemplate=

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf

I have a piece of code.

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Intest/GeneratePINs/{ID}/{count}/{SameID}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public void GeneratePINs(string ID, string count, string SameID)
    {
```

I am new to WCF and json, can you advise me what is that? I guess that is to retrieve values from UI and pass them to service??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a method in a WCF service that is accessible through a HTTP Get call.

The Get call must follow the outline given by the UriTemplate parameter.

The URI Template also says how parameters for the WCF Service Method need to be passed in the query string.

It gives a response in JSON (that said, its void so doesnt really do anything).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, is it a call from client? The parameters are from client?

Comment: the parameters in this case would be when the client accesses a url such as http://www.yourservice.com/Intest/GeneratePINs/a/2/c and in that example, parameter ID would be "a", count would be "2" and SameID would be "c" - so would be equivalent of a normal method call of GeneratePins("a","2","c");